# Why does creating a frozenset out of a list in python convert the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

In python, when creating a frozenset out of a list, for example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=frozenset(a)
```

iterating over the items in 'a' iterates over 3 items, as expected, yet iterating over the items in 'b' also iterates over the same 3 items. I expected 'b' to contain only 1 item, the list 'a'. Why does this happen?

Comment: Take a look at the [`frozenset` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). `frozenset` "Return[s] a new set or frozenset object whose elements are taken from iterable."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`frozenset` takes an iterable as an argument, and constructs a set containing the elements of the iterable. If you want a set that contains the *list* itself, you are out of luck: a list, being mutable, is not hashable, and therefore cannot be an element of a set, frozen or otherwise.

What you *can* do, is first create a tuple containing the elements of the list, then make a frozen set that contains *that* tuple. Note that the elements of the original list, recursively, must also be hashable.

```
>>> frozenset(a)
frozenset([1, 2, 3])
>>> frozenset((tuple(a),))
frozenset([(1, 2, 3)])
```